# Ubuntu nosound issue

Tags: sound

I did a fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04.1 in my laptop HP envy 17. The audio is not working. However the audio works when connected to a HDMI TV. 
I tried the following steps:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure
http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/
http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1404/

But no luck, so far. I have installed debian-7.7.0, mint-17 and Ubuntu 14.04 again. However nothing works.

Another sub question is, I see that some of the configurations survive even after complete formatting. Is it possible to do a clean wipe and reinstall. If so will that help?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install and run "pavucontrol" (**Pulseaudio volume control**) ?
In pavucontrol, go to the "output devices" tab:
 You will  probably see 2 devices (HDMI and  internal soundcard)  .
You can choose which one is active by clicking the green "define as alternative" button that is near each soundcard .
You can also try changing profile in "configuration" tab.

Comment: Yes, I have installed pavucontrol. In the output devices tab, there are two devices HDMI and "Dummy Output". It is not showing up the internal soundcard.

Comment: can you copy in your answer this command result  : `aplay -l `   ( It should show 2 devices : HDMI and internal audio)